# MKMapView not staying rotated

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mkmapview

Easy to reproduce:
- create a new project
- put an MKMapView on the screen
- try to rotate it with 2 fingers

It rotates a little and stops, and when you release the fingers, it goes back to the original position.

How do I make it stay rotated?
And rotate as much as I want?

I'm using latest iOS (8.something), iPhone 6 simulator and Swift.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
Actually there is no solution, what was happening is that MKMapView does not allow you to stay rotated if the map region is too big.
If you zoom in you can rotate normally.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this 
Gloabally declare :

```
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
```

And in viewdidload:

```
let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)
    centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
```

And then create a helper class:

```
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
            regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapview.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz I have edited my answer. Please check that

Comment: Surprisingly it did work... But I have no idea why, and I don't wanna change the map region.

Comment: This is not a solution, I don't want to change the map region. Also, did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try with rotateEnabled property of MKMapView :

rotateEnabled -
A Boolean value indicating whether the map camera’s heading information is used.

Declaration

SWIFT
var rotateEnabled: Bool

When this property is set to YES and a valid camera is associated with the map, the camera’s heading angle is used to rotate the plane of the map around its center point. When this property is set to NO, the camera’s heading angle is ignored and the map is always oriented so that true north is situated at the top of the map view.

Comment: This property is already set to true (or YES in Objective-C) by default

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `CLLocationManager.didUpdateLocations` (part of CLLocationManagerDelegate) to get notified when the location manager retrieves the current location and don't do anything there:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    // Don't do update the map to the new location
}
```